# SignInManager<User> gives "a second operation started on this context"

Tags: asp.net-identity, entity-framework-core, asp.net-core-2.0

I have read the following questions before asking:

- [A second operation started on this context before a previous operation completed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43861496/a-second-operation-started-on-this-context-before-a-previous-operation-completed)
- [How to fix 'A second operation started on this context before [...]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46395150/how-to-fix-a-second-operation-started-on-this-context-before-a-previous-operati)
- [UserManager Error - A second operation started on this context before [...]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26351917/usermanager-error-a-second-operation-started-on-this-context-before-a-previous)
- [A second operation started on this context before a previous [...]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49707014/a-second-operation-started-on-this-context-before-a-previous-asynchronous-operat)

Following the advice given in the answer to these questions I have checked that my `async`call had its `await` directive and I verified that nothing was configured as `static` in the `Startup.cs`

I get the following error

> InvalidOperationException: A second operation started on this context before a previous operation completed. Any instance members are not guaranteed to be thread safe.

when the following code is called twice in a row.

*code reduced to the minimum needed to understand*

```
public async Task<IActionResult> Login(LoginViewModel model)
{

    /* [...] */

    var result = await _signInManager.PasswordSignInAsync(model.Email, model.Password, isPersistent: model.RememberMe, lockoutOnFailure: false);

    if (result.Succeeded)
    {
        /* [...] */
    }

    /* [...] */
}
```

the sign-in manager is declared as `private readonly SignInManager<User> _signInManager;` and is obtained via dependency injection through the constructor.

The DbContext and Identity context are configured as services in the code below. Nothing is declared as `static` as far as I know.

```
services.AddDbContext<RelaxationDbContext>(options =>
    options.UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetConnectionString("RelaxationDbContext")));

services.AddIdentity<User, AppIdentityRole>()
    .AddEntityFrameworkStores<RelaxationDbContext>()
    .AddDefaultTokenProviders()
    .AddErrorDescriber<FrenchIdentityErrorDescriber>();
```

Why am I getting an error there ? Is there a bug in the framework or have I done something wrong ?
How can I prevent this error from occurring in the future ?

Comment: I think you have to use `_context.SaveChanges();` between the two operations

Comment: @viveknuna I tried adding `_context.SaveChanges();` but the same error still happens. I also looked at other examples such as [this one](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/asp.net_core/asp.net_core_log_in_and_log_out.htm) and didn't see a call to `SaveChanges` after `PasswordSignInAsync` so I assume that this call is done internally ?

Comment: Can you try AsNoTracking in your code?

Comment: I do not make any calls to a `DbSet` myself, everything is managed internally by the `SignInManager`. Where exactly do you want me to add the `AsNoTracking()` call ?

Comment: Or you can try making the first call sync

Comment: I just tried removing the `await` directive before the call to `_signInManager.PasswordSignInAsync` but the same error still occurs :-(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out, since I couldn't figure out how to seed a test user in the in my `DbContext` using `HasData` because I didn't have any mean of hashing the password I ended up generating the user in the constructor of the main controller using the following code

```
var findByEmailAsync = _userManager.FindByEmailAsync("foo@foo.foo");
if (findByEmailAsync.Result == null)
    _userManager?.CreateAsync(new User()
    {
        Id = "37846734-172e-4149-8cec-6f43d1eb3f60",
        Email = "foo@foo.foo",
        UserName = "foo@foo.foo"
    }, "Password_1");
```

Then, since I am currently working on the "change email" feature, after changing the email and confirming the change the user tried to log back in. And hell, that's where the shenanigans came in !

Since the user had changed email the `FindByEmailAsync` method didn't find it in the database leading to a call to `CreateAsync`. For some reason this call would sometimes run properly and sometimes crash ... but most of the time the app would crash on the next call to the `_userManager` which happend almost always during a login attempt.

I do not really understand why it is THIS error that is returned instead of a `duplicate id` one ...

As a temporary fix until I figure out how to seed users in the database I've replace my code's first line with this one `var findByEmailAsync = _userManager.FindByIdAsync("37846734-172e-4149-8cec-6f43d1eb3f60");`

Comment: Notice that the call to `_userManager?.CreateAsync(...)` isn't `await`-ed, so a second operation could be started on the `DbContext` of this request.

Comment: Hooooo ! Good eye Milord ! I'll try to get rind of this approach altogether but that might very well be the reason why iI get this specific error instead of a duplicate ID one. Thanks !

Answer (score 0):

This problem is caused because the context was unable to perform first operation and got stuck.
Most common reasons are

1. You are using context with async but your operation is taking longer to complete.
2. Connection string is wrong due to which operation is taking longer to complete.

Comment: The call to `_signInManager.PasswordSignInAsync()` returns almost immediately on the first call. I do not understand your second point ? The connexion string works correctly.